Sync between two thread in Swift
When I start the app, I have:
class PremiumManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
   static let sharedInstance = PremiumManager()    

  static func loadProducts() {
     sharedInstance.load()
  }

  func load() {
     let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:["some_id"])
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
   }

   func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) { 
      //so some work
   }

   func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
   }
}

In AppDelegate I do this:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 PremiumManager.loadProducts()
}

Now in my MainViewController inside viewDidLoad I have code:
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     initVars()
     checkData()
  }

  func initVars() {
    //some variables init
  }

  func checkData() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
       //do some background tasks to sync data with server using inited variables
    }
  }
}

The problem is, I want to run checkData only after productsRequest is finished (sucesfully or failed) and also after initVars is finished.
How to sync this? I was thinking to use static global Semaphore, but from what I have googled, it Semaphores are not quite recommended.
In all solutions I have think of, the both classes require to see each other, but I dont have references from one to another.

You can use Combine/NotificationCenter to publish a custom message upon completion.
Premium Manager - use NotificationCenter.default.post to post a notification when productsRequest completes.
MainViewController - add a varsAreInited: Bool property.
MainViewController - add a NotificationCenter.default.publisher to trigger on the Premium Manager's message - in this closure, if varsAreInited == true, call your checkData func.
